# Help starting a game from the terminal

Tags: command-line, server

I am trying to start a server (Bedrock Server) from the desktop terminal.

If I type `/home/snap/bedrock-server/./bedrock_server` it seems to start loading, but I get errors reading the server properties file.

However it works if I go the folder, then open a terminal windows and type `./bedrock_server`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

What about that instead ? ;-)

```
./home/snap/bedrock-server/bedrock_server
```

Also, the script/app you're executing might have not considered that you are not in the current folder and you cannot do much about that if you can't edit the script implied by adding the "cd directory" at the beginning